# How do I correctly determine realis vs irrealis or indicative vs subjunctive in this sentence?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, irrealis-were, if-whether, indicative

`I stared at him to see if he were just a cartoon character.`

or

`I stared at him to see if he was just a cartoon character.`

The intended meaning of the two sentences above are that due to `him` (his behavior) that the writer is (`I am`) staring at, that is, in the writer's imagination, they are imagining because of his absurd statements prior, that he is cartoonish. The writer is being sarcastic, because they know that he is not actually an animated cartoon, but rather he is just acting like one.

I'm confused about whether it should be `was` or `were`, however (I'm a native English speaker) my intuition tells me it should be `was` and another person is telling me that it should be the subjunctive `were`.

Any help gladly welcomed!

Comment: *If* here is a synonym of *whether*. There's nothing conditional about it. Use *was*.

Comment: Thanks Clare. The speaker is in a situation with an actual human (`him`, in this case, along with others, though I don't think that it matters that there are others present in addition to `him`), so the speaker clearly knows that he is not a literally a cartoon, but what they're implying is that his behavior is such that they are sarcastically 'staring at him' to see if he might be a cartoon (even though they know he is not). Does that change anything?

Comment: Everything you describe is talking is in the realm of the real. The speaker is sarcastically  "not sure" the human is a  human, so use *was*.

Comment: Thanks again. I believe you make clear that it's all in the realm of the real, regardless of whether it's imagined or not. In other words, they were really imagining, it's not a thought experiment where they were imagining that they could have imagined that. I've updated my question to clarify it, I believe!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/6699/77227 I'm reluctant to recommend reading that whole page, since I think some of the answers are wrong, but that particular answer seems correct to me.

Comment: Even if it *was/were* irrealis, like in this sentence, you could use *was* in all but formal writing, especially in British English. In general, the only time *was* sounds horrible (to many) is in *If I was you*. (I'd say *If I were you*...)

Comment: @Clare Whether it be conditional or not, *whether* doesn't obviate the subjunctive.

Comment: OP, what are you asking? Are you trying to distinguish the pair realis/irrealis from the pair indicative/subjunctive? Or are you trying to distinguish irrealis/subjunctive from realis/indicative?

Comment: Also related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148710/reported-speech-with-was-and-were. The second answer gives an example from CGEL that is very close to the OP's.

Comment: I see *was/were* as a backshifted verb. (related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204893/is-the-concept-of-backshifted-past-tense-in-reported-speech-applicable-to-othe), and as such, expect to often see *were* and *was* used interchangeably.

Comment: @sumelic That answer is utterly incorrect!! Read Clare's comments here ...

Comment: Hi @Phil Sweet ~ Really I was just trying to figure out whether to use was or were here, but in doing so after a bit of searching here and on other blog posts it seemed to come down to subjunctive (what my other offline editor's opinion was saying to me) as well as this new thing I'd never heard of: irrealis (vs realis). So, the truth: I don't know which axes those four fall on--that's part of my comments on Araucaria's answer below--asking how those four (5) terms: realis / irrealis and subjunctive / indicative (and I suppose now a fifth: interrogative) are related. Thanks for asking.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/617380/2085). @PhilSweet I see you were here, too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I stared at him to see if he was just a cartoon character.

The sentence above has a clause which looks like a conditional adjunct:

- if he was just a cartoon character

If this was indeed a conditional antecedent, then we could use either *was* or *were* here, assuming that the conditional was a so-called subjunctive conditional.

However, the *if*-string above is not part of a conditional construction in the Original Poster's sentence. It is an interrogative clause. We can apply a simple test here, which is to replace the word *if* with the interrogative subordinator *whether*. If the sentence is still grammatical and means the same thing, then we know that this is an interrogative clause and not a conditional adjunct:

> I stared at him to see whether he was just a cartoon character.

The sentence above means the same thing as the Original Poster's example sentence, so we can be confident that the string involved is an interrogative clause. Because this is a straightforward interrogative clause, there is no possibility of using irrealis *were* here.

Comment: Thank you. My intuition seems correct. I'll use *was*! Also, because this passes the "substitute whether for if" test, then we both (a) know that it cannot be irrealis *were*, nor (b) can it be a subjunctive either, because it's an interrogative. Is my summary part (b) correct as well? In general does irrealis always (or only) apply to subjunctive? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, is the preference (necessity) for *was* the same in (North) American English as in British English? Again, *was* sounds more correct to me, but I want to give the person insisting this was a subjunctive case and hence should be *were* a fair shake! Grazie mille!

Comment: @likethesky That's right. And, yes,  it is the same in US English too!

Comment: Is it always a subjunctive/irrealis when saying `as if`, e.g., these are interrogatives--and should use `was`/`wasn't`: `I wondered if she was planning` and `If she was to marry, a man would rule` and these are subjunctives (as well as irrealis)--and should use `were`/`weren't`: `he wouldn't talk to her directly, but would speak about her as if she weren’t there`, `I felt as if I were a goldfish trying to escape`, `It was as if I were drawn to wandering around`; & no `as if`: `how, if I were to die, all of that would be gone`? Did I get all of those correct? The subjunctives seem most tricky.

Comment: Happy to take this to a wiki discussion page instead, if that's more appropriate; I had one more example arise, `I started speculating if it were possible that my anger would cause` ... using your substitution test, I believe that this one is an interrogative, so it should *not* use `were`, but instead `was`, meaning that `I started speculating if it was possible that my anger would cause` is the correct construction. Thanks again!

Comment: let me know if you have any thoughts on the above two comments.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer.